# How to get specific values (eg. battery2, servo outputs) available in Mission Planner through Dronekit?

Tags: dronekit-python

I am currently using `dronekit-python` to implement somewhat of a [Mission Planner](https://ardupilot.org/planner/) clone, as an API. I've generally been able to replicate most important features from Mission Planner; however, some features don't seem to be present.

One such feature is reading live servo outputs, which can be done in Setup > Mandatory Hardware > Servo Output (image below). I have been able to emulate getting/setting the output's function, min, trim, max, and reversed values through parameters. However, I cannot seem to access the live position values through dronekit. How would you go about this?

[image: Servo Outputs Page]

A second feature is reading specific values from the plane, beyond the class attributes present. This is available in Mission Planner when double-clicking a value in the Quick pane in order to change what measurement is displayed (image below). For my use case, I'd like to specifically access `battery_voltage2` and `battery_remaining2`, as these are vital measurements for our system. I tried using `vehicle.battery` in dronekit, but this seems to only display data from battery 1. Any ideas?

[image: List of Quick data items]

Thank You so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to get the battery information and other information from the drone by using Mavlink messages. For battery information, look at the [BATTERY_STATUS (#147)](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#BATTERY_STATUS) Mavlink message. For servo information, look at the [SERVO_OUTPUT_RAW (#36)](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#SERVO_OUTPUT_RAW) message.

In order to receive these messages, look into using [message listeners](https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/mavlink_messages.html) from dronekit-python. You should be able to receive and parse the Mavlink message.

In general, you can use message listeners and the dronekit-python [message factory](https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automodule.html#dronekit.Vehicle.message_factory) to receive and send Mavlink messages, which allows you more control than some of the built-in dronekit functions. If you decide to control the drone this way, though, be careful because it's pretty easy to mess up your logic and have the drone behave unexpectedly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I looked into this too, but it seems that the listeners are only triggered when the value *changes*, and I'm unsure of how to directly read the value at one time. For example, is there a way to read the exact value of the Mavlink message on connect, before it has changed?

Comment: Update - I tried it and it works perfectly, with updates about every second. Thank You so much!